# Call naked function from one to another?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

When I try to call declspec(naked) function to another function, I get an error
that according to the function prototype it must returns a value but
when I try to return a value I get another error says naked function could not return a value.

```
__declspec(naked) void bar()    {
    __asm   {
        nop
        ret
    }
}

__declspec(naked) NTSTATUS WINAPI foo(int a, int b) {
    bar();
    return NTSTATUS(1);
}
```

All of that is reasonable because naked functions dont create a stackframe for the function, hence
calling to another function is an error unless the programmer explicitly creates a stackframe.
However when I try to create a stackframe and do stack alignment in the right way I get an error.

How can I call from a naked function to another correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Naked functions [don't support return statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d12973a.aspx)

> The following rules and limitations apply to naked functions:
>
> - The return statement is not permitted.

you should deal with the stack frame **and** the return value yourself, e.g.

```
__declspec( naked ) void bar()    {
    __asm   {
        nop
        ret
    }
}
__declspec(naked) bool foo(int a, int b) {
    bar();
    __asm   {
        mov al,1
        ret
    }
}

int main() {
    bool return_value = foo(2, 2);
    std::cout << return_value; // 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

naked function means compiler is not going to write prologue(setting esp and ebp) and epilogue(resetting esp and ebp) for you. Since compiler is not writing epilogue so you can't ask it to return some value for you by using "return" keyword.
//prologue

```
// simple prologue
      push ebp
      mov ebp, esp

// simple epilogue
      mov eax, ret_var  //by default eax holds return value
      mov esp, ebp
      pop ebp
```